# Implement interfaces in java

Tags: java, interface

I have declared this interface:

```
public interface Filter 
{   
/**
  Determines whether to accept an object.
  @param x the object to be filtered
  @return true to accept an object, false otherwise
*/
boolean accept(Object x);   
}
```

So Now what I need to do is to implement it along with another interface already declared and implemented in the class. So my question is if I can implement both interfaces in the same class in this way.

```
public class DataSet implements Measurer, implements Filter{
 ......
 }

or

 public class DataSet implements Measurer, Filter{
 .....
 }
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to compile with either syntax? What was the result?

Comment: did you tried ? take a minute in eclipse to do so.

Comment: If you're asking whether you can implement two interfaces in the same class, the answer is yes.

Comment: Did you do even a minute of research before posting this?

Comment: JAJAJA. SCARY TO ASK A STUPID QUESTION, NOW I KNOW IT WAS A STUPID QUESTION.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java supports multiple implementation of interfaces. The proper syntax is:

```
public class A implements B, C{

}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `public class DataSet implements Measurer, Filter` is the correct option. But seriously you would have tried it yourself faster than asking here.